# two elements inline block - no flow when resized

Tags: css

I am looking for the best way to have multiple columns using inline-block.  Everything works great except for when the browser is resized.  The 2nd column will be pushed under the first column as one would expect with inline-block.  I understand why that happens, what I need to know is if there is a way to make a horizontal scroll instead of pushing the second column down.  I thought overflow:hidden would work, but it does not seem to.

I am not setting any widths right now and would like to keep this as fluid as possible.

```
<div>
    <div id="col1"></div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
</div>
```

col1 and col2 are inline-block with no width set and they display side by side when the browser view is wide enough.  When the users browser is re-sized smaller, col2 displays underneath col1.  I want them to always be side by side and have a horizontal scroll if needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) to the parent of the elements that have `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I wanted.  It makes sense to have to use that because typically it is text that inside of inline elements.

Comment: Taking a second look at it, this does not appear to push the outer div's width out to be the size of the combined inner cols.  Any way to do that?

Comment: Ah.  Just figured it out.  Also add overflow-x: scroll to the parent does what I want.

Comment: overflow-x: scroll adds a scrollbar for the element not the entire page.

Comment: If you haven't yet resolved your new problem, try `float: left` or `display: inline-block` on the parent `div`.

Comment: thanks again! Both worked. I am still trying to wrap my head around why they work like that. (no pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:500px">   // <=== try to make fix width
    <div id="col1"></div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
</div>
```

or try

```
<div style="min-width:500px">   // <=== try to make fix width
    <div id="col1"></div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I wanted to try to keep it fluid based on the content, but I am not sure there is a way.

Comment: @user595078 if you wan some overflow-x - so you have to tell the browser " what is boundary for which to start make scroll" - hence you need fix width

Comment: Yah thats what I thought.  It sucks because col2 contains a table that contains fluid contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `min-width` to outer div. So it applies only when window is smaller, and doesn't fixes actual size.